# How to extract data from file that has similar data in each cell in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data in an excel file (please see the images).
[image]

How can I extract the data and get an output similar to the below image,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture of my test set-up

[image]

In B1 Enter:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1;" ";REPT(" ";999));(COLUMN(A:A)-COLUMN($A1))*999+1;999));MIN(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1;" ";REPT(" ";999));(COLUMN(A:A)-COLUMN($A1))*999+1;999))&"0123456789"))-1);"")
```

You can now drag this to the right and get all the texts.

**Note** that my regional settings has ";" as a separator you migt need to replace them with ","